# Interactions between HTTP and websocket connections in Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

I have a frontend consumer that handles HTTP requests (webhooks)

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from channels.generic.http import AsyncHttpConsumer
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import myapp.models
import redis

@csrf_exempt 
class frontEndConsumer(AsyncHttpConsumer):

    async def http_request(self, request):

        await self.channel_layer.group_add("link", self.channel_name)
        await self.channel_layer.group_send("link",
            {
               "type": "websocket.reg",
               "where": "webhook",
               "message": "test message",
            })

#channel layer functions
    async def webhook_reg(self, event):
        print("WH: message from " + event["where"] + ": " + event["message"]
        # make response
        fulfillmentText = "device connected"
        fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': fulfillmentText}
        fulfillmentText = json.dumps(fulfillmentText).encode('utf-8') 
        await self.send_response(200, fulfillmentText, 
            headers=[(b"Content-Type", b"text/plain"),])
```

and I have a backend consumer that handles websocket connections.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
import redis
import myapp.models
account = redis.Redis(db=0)

class backEndConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, type):
        await self.channel_layer.group_add("link", self.channel_name)
        print("channel name: " + self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

#channel layer functions 
    async def websocket_reg(self, event):
        print("WS: message from " + event["where"] + ": " + event["message"])

        await self.channel_layer.group_send("link",
            {
               "type": "webhook.reg",
               "where": "websocket",
               "message": "msg from websocket",
            })
        await self.send(event["message"])
```

I start them in procfile with:

```
web: daphne APbackend.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0
```

I am using django channels to have the front and back talk to each other. In my code, I'm trying to get both sides to send messages to each other.

1. I would establish websocket connection
2. have webhook send a http request to my front end.
3. front end would send a message to the backend (via channel messaging)
4. backend would send a message to the frontend.
5. front end message would finish the http request.

But this doesn't work, step 4, with the message going back to the front end saying the handler is missing. Why is that?

Comment: `csrf_exempt` I dont think you can use this on a AsyncHttpConsumer consumer.

can you share how you are configuring you ASGI application? how you are using `frontEndConsumer` and `backEndConsumer`

Comment: application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        path('ws/', backEndConsumer),
    ]),
    "http": URLRouter([
        path('webhook/', frontEndConsumer),
    ]), is the way i configured the asgi application. http routes to frontEnd, websocket routes to backEnd. I might add a web page so I am splitting it up using URLrouter. csrf_exempt is what i put in because of a tutorial. I am not sure of the details of what it does, or if it is applicable for me.

Comment: the `csrf_exempt` has no effect in channels.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same group to talk in both directions this means when you send `webhook.reg` from the backend it will end up trying to call the function `webhook_reg` on each `backEndConsumer` instance but there is no such method there.

You should create 2 groups.

- `backend_to_frontend`
- `frontend_to_backend`

---

- the `frontend` should `group_add` the `backend_to_frontend`
- the `backend` should `group_add` the `frontend_to_backend`

&

- in the `backend` you should `group_send` to the `backend_to_frontend`
- in the `frontend` you should `group_send` to the `frontend_to_backend`

Comment: Knowing that http_requests ends its context if i send the response definitely helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. Turns out for my design I don't need the broadcast features of a group_send, and just needed channel names!

Comment: Thanks for these, creating two groups worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using either two group names or two channel names. Also knowing http_reponse would end the http_request context helped me debug why I wasn't able to get message back to dialogflow.

Thanks!